# Terraform-AWS 0.10.3: Unable to destroy cluster with instance that has deleted AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm uncertain of how terraform is supposed to behave in this scenario:

1. We bring up a cluster of instances, one of which has an ami that was deleted while the cluster is running.
2. We try to destroy this cluster and terraform fails in the refresh phase because the query trying to find the ami fails.

In my mind, the ami shouldn't be needed any longer in order to destroy a cluster - the instance already exists, and so terraform should destroy the cluster.

Perhaps there is a work-around here? Or should I file an issue?

Comment: Sorry to ask but do you mean an EBS volume? I know this issue exist with ebs volume and it a bug in Terraform https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2957

Comment: Nope, good question, but this is for AMIs, more specifically AMIs for g2 instances. When the AMI that the g2 instance was based created from is deleted, then terraform is unable to refresh.

Comment: This seems like it might be an issue with either your AMI lifecycle or how you're using the data source. I'd recommend tagging AMIs so that new ones would be automatically picked up by the same AMI data source filter (and using most_recent to select the new one) and then you shouldn't find yourself in this situation.

Comment: In this specific use-case we need to be able to have pinned versions, otherwise what you're saying would surely work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Terraform refreshes all resources before taking any actions to ensure that it is working from the most up-to-date record of the state of the world.

In situations where this is not suitable -- such as the one you've described here -- this behavior can be disabled by passing the option `-refresh=false` to the `terraform destroy` command. In this case, Terraform will use the values already saved in the state from a previous run, skipping the "refresh" step that would normally update them.